# $abc$-formula: $D >= 0$ or $D > 0$?

Tags: calculus, quadratics

I don't really understand when to put $>$ or $<$ , $>=$  or $<=$ when working with the $abc$-formula.

This is the $abc$-formula:

We have a quadratic equation:
$$ax^2+bx+c$$
Now for the $abc$-formula:
$$D = (b)^2 -4\times a c$$
$$D > 0  \text{  two solutions, } D < 0 \text{  no solutions} D = 0 \text{  one solution}$$
$$x = \frac{-b\pm \sqrt{D}}{2\times a}$$

---

Now, for example,  the following problem is given:

$$f_{p}(x) = x^3 +5x^2 +px$$

For what value of $p$ has $f_{p}$ no extreme value? So I would presume we would need $D < 0$

Here's how I worked out this problem:

$$f'_{p}(x) = 3x^2 +10x+p = 0$$
$$D = (10)^2 -4 \times 3 \times p$$
$$100- 12 p $$

$D < 0$ gives us no solution so:

$$100-12p < 0$$
$$-12p < -100$$
$$p > \frac{-100}{-12}$$
$$p > \frac{25}{3} $$

I solved it correctly but my book says it has to be the following:

$$100-12p \leqslant 0$$
$$-12p \leqslant -100$$
$$p \geqslant \frac{-100}{-12}$$
$$p \geqslant \frac{25}{3} $$

(If you need more information please ask and I'll supply.)

All help is highly appreciated.

Cro-Magnon

Comment: @andréNicolas I thought so too, but even my teacher said the book was right.  So should I just disregard my book and my teach? :P

Comment: There's something a bit strange here, as $0$ is a root of $f_p$ for all $p$...

Comment: I believe you meant to ask about roots of $f_p'$, not $f_p$.  Assuming that's the case, then I'd say you were right.  $-\frac 53$ is a (double) root of the quadratic in question.  I'd ask the teacher why that root shouldn't be counted.

Comment: @lulu yes I'm sorry! I'll change that right away.

Comment: If $D=0$, then $f_p^\prime$ has a double root.  This root wont be a extremal value but an inflextion point.

Comment: Now that you have modified the problem, the book/teacher are right. If $f_p'(x)\le 0$, then there is no extreme value. For example, consider $f_p(x)=x^3$. This is always increasing, though it "hesitates" at $0$.

Comment: @andréNicolas Thanks, I'll see if I can wrap my head around this.

Comment: @andréNicolas I get it now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. The (nice) function $f_p(x)$  has no local max or min precisely if the derivative never changes sign, that is, is always $\ge 0$ or $\le 0$.